# How to mask a video with an image on opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, mask

I want to create a mask over the whole human figure and replace it with an image that is responsive to the moving human figure. The image attached will give you a better idea of what is I mean.
[image: Still 1][image: Still 2]
The Image in the background will be still and won't move but the figure will seem like it punched a hole into the foreground. The figures however they move will go over the static background image and show the contents of the image. The figures, if they overlap as seen in the first image (see overlapping leg) should not break the mask and should still display the contents of the background.

Comment: How are the figures defined ?

Comment: Assuming that the figures are known as a continuous outline drawn on a white mask image in black, you can fill the inside in gray. Then you scan the mask image and replace every gray pixel by the corresponding pixel in the background image. If there are several backgrounds (for several figures), you can fill every figure with a different gray.