# Enhancing OpenCV Masking

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, mask

I made a program that applies a mask over an object as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756813/how-to-mask-a-video-with-an-image-on-opencv?noredirect=1#comment126810888_71756813) StackOverflow question. I did so using colour thresholding and making the mask select only the colour range of human skin (I don't know if it works for white people as I am not white and it works well for me). the problem is when I run it, some greys (grey area on the wall or a shadow) are also picked up on the mask and it is applied there. [image: program when running]
I wanted to know whether there was a way to remove the unnecessary bits in the background, and/or if there was a way using object detection I could solve this. PS I tried using createBackgroundSubtractorGMG/MOG/etc but that came out very weird and way worse.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import bitwise_and
from cv2 import COLOR_HSV2BGR
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt




cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

image = cv2.imread('yesh1.jpg')
bg = cv2.imread('kruger.jpg')
bg = cv2.cvtColor(bg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

kernel1 = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((10,10),np.uint8)

while (1):
     ret, frame = cap.read()
     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
     lowerBound = np.array([1, 1, 1])
     upperBound = np.array([140, 255 ,140])

     mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lowerBound, upperBound)
     blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask,(5,5),0)
     ret1,mask = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
     mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel1)
     contourthickness = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
     res = bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
     crop_bg = bg[0:480, 0:640]
     final = frame + res
     final = np.where(contourthickness != 0, crop_bg, final)


     cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
     cv2.imshow('Final', final) # TIS WORKED BBYY



     key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     if key == 27:
         break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT:
Following @fmw42 's comment, I am adding the original image as well as a screenshot of how the different frames look. The masked image also changes colour. Something to fix that will also be helpful.
[image: background image]
[image]

Comment: Post your original image so others can test your code and see where it might be improved rather than trying to remove the bad noise. Perhaps something earlier in your process will help. Possibly it is the otsu thresholding that is not adequate.

Comment: @fmw42  I added the original image

Comment: You are never going to get a very robust solution using OpenCV basics. I found this [backgroundremover](https://github.com/nadermx/backgroundremover#advance-usage-for-video) package that works great (there are other deep learning based solutions that are specialized in human body). Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlJZ0.png).

Comment: As per @Rotem suggestion, see also http://remove.bg.  I found that to be the best online bg removal

Answer (score 1):

@Jeremi. Your code working 100%. Using White wall for background. Avoid door(it is not white, it is cream), shadow around edge, to prevent noising. If you have white bed sheet or white walls. I am using Raspberry pi 4b/8gb, 4k monitor. I can't get actual size of window.

Here is output:
[image]

What you see on my output. I placed my hand behind white sheet closer to camera. I do not have white wall on my room. My room is greener. That why you see logo on background. Btw, I can move my hand no problem.